# Mysql I get trigger error says Expected whitespace(s) before delimiter

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following trigger but I get **Expected whitespace(s) before delimiter** error near 'SELECT SUM(money_amount) FROM salary_transaction into x WHERE Salary_Transaction'

Trigger code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE trigger Remainig_money_calc
AFTER INSERT on salary_transaction FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE
x,y Decimal(10,2)
SELECT SUM(money_amount) FROM salary_transaction into x WHERE Salary_Transaction_Id= NEW.Salary_Transaction_Id; 
SELECT employees.Salary into y WHERE NEW.Worker_Id=employees.Worker_Id;
insert into debt_alerts(Remaining_money) VALUES(y-x)  ;
END
DELIMITER$$
```

*For complete codes those my tables and relationships*

Employees table

```
CREATE TABLE `Employees`
(
  `Worker_Id` Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Worker_Name` Char(150) NOT NULL,
  `Job` Varchar(100),
  `Salary` Decimal(10,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Worker_Id`)
);
```

Salary_Transaction table

```
CREATE TABLE `Salary_Transaction`
(
  `Salary_Transaction_Id` Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `money_amount` Decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `Worker_Id` Int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Salary_Transaction_Id`)
)
;
```

debt_alerts  table

```
CREATE TABLE `debt_alerts`
(
  `Debt_alert_id` Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Salary_Transaction_Id` Int,
  `Remaining_money` Decimal(10,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Debt_alert_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
 ;
```

Relationships

```
ALTER TABLE `debt_alerts` ADD CONSTRAINT `Relationship23` FOREIGN KEY (`Salary_Transaction_Id`) REFERENCES `salary_transaction` (`Salary_Transaction_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
;


ALTER TABLE `salary_transaction` ADD CONSTRAINT `Relationship11` FOREIGN KEY (`Worker_Id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`Worker_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
;
```

**EDIT**

```
ALTER TABLE `debt_alerts` ADD CONSTRAINT `Relationship23` FOREIGN KEY (`Salary_Transaction_Id`) REFERENCES `salary_transaction` (`Salary_Transaction_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
;
```

Comment: Add `;` after `DECLARE x,y Decimal(10,2)`. Replace last `DELIMITER$$` with `$$ DELIMITER ;` But the best way is to combine all 3 queries into one and exclude variable, BEGIN-END and delimiter reassign.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE trigger Remainig_money_calc
AFTER INSERT ON Salary_Transaction 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO debt_alerts(Remaining_money, Salary_Transaction_Id) 
SELECT y.y-x.x, NEW.Salary_Transaction_Id
FROM ( SELECT SUM(money_amount) x
       FROM Salary_Transaction 
       WHERE Salary_Transaction_Id = NEW.Salary_Transaction_Id ) x
JOIN ( SELECT Employees.Salary y 
       FROM Employees
       WHERE NEW.Employee_Id=Employees.Employee_Id 
       LIMIT 1 ) y;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=70799967a77e6bf83a11ffc5d82d0cb2)

Comment: This code works correctly but at a first transaction only ,but at the second transaction  it does not subtract the  sum of all debt money in previous transactions  from the   the salary of that employee    please see the Edit I added a code

Comment: and Salary_Transaction_Id value does not inserted in debt_alerts table

Comment: @PHPFan Please edit [the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9c060cb42694bf9715a954236b1933d), specify your MySQL version, add sample data, reproduce the problems described. Post new link to the fiddle.

Comment: [link]https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=cfd33ad641e941ac9b370d781ef16927[/link]  work_id,work_name columns had been changed to Employee_Id,Employee_Name

Comment: AKina https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=cfd33ad641e941ac9b370d781ef16927  please note that  work_id,work_name columns had been changed to Employee_Id,Employee_Nam

Comment: @PHPFan Please run the fiddle and ensure that your editions gives the fiddle which doesn't demonstrate synthactical or logical errors. Post only link to correct fiddle.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=97f6ca5ec3408e44a5deb7179668bffc

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=23fe550c31733afe192697ce8a977545

Comment: @PHPFan Oops... the problem fixed. Looking at your `insert into debt_alerts(Remaining_money) VALUES(y-x)` I have not added `Salary_Transaction_Id` column insertion... See edited code and fiddle.

Comment: No the remaining_money in the last row should be 997000.00 not 998000.00!

Comment: I changed the line in your code SELECT SUM(money_amount) FROM salary_transaction into x WHERE Salary_Transaction_Id= NEW.Salary_Transaction_Id;   to  WHERE Salary_Transaction_Id= Salary_Transaction_Id and now it works fine

Comment: @PHPFan *to WHERE Salary_Transaction_Id= Salary_Transaction_Id* Why not `WHERE Salary_Transaction_Id IS NOT NULL`? this is the same...

Comment: But the trigger edited by me generate minus values in debt_alerts table if there are more than one employees in salary_transaction table

Comment: I said WHERE Salary_Transaction_Id= Salary_Transaction_Id  because  I need the specific Salary_Transaction_Id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222447/discussion-between-phpfan-and-akina).

Comment: @PHPFan *I said `WHERE Salary_Transaction_Id= Salary_Transaction_Id`* - this is ALWAYS true until `Salary_Transaction_Id` is NULL. 2 copies of the same value are always equal if this value is not NULL. No exclusion in MySQL.

Comment: yeah really what do you suggest

Comment: please see edit https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=51390bf456af62fbf713cf71198dbf21